# Is $\int f=f-1\iff f(\cdot)=e^{\cdot}$ proved this way correct?

Tags: definite-integrals, power-series, alternative-proof

I saw this on math overflow and made me wonder, why does it work, is it rigorous, can we really factor like this, and where can we use similar tricks;

Let $\int$ denote $\int_0^x$

Then solve $$\int f=f-1 \iff 1=\left (1-\int\right )f\iff f=\left (1-\int\right )^{-1} 1$$

Then with geometric series

$$f=\left(1+\int+\iint+\iiint+\cdots\right)1=1+\int_0^x1~dx+\int_0^x\int_0^x1~dx+\cdots=1+x+\frac{x^2}{2}+\frac{x^3}{6}+\cdots=e^x$$

Comment: $\int $, like $D = \dfrac {d}{dx}$ is a linear operator, and there is an algebra one can define using such operators.

Comment: It isn't sensible to use the same variable in the $dx$ as you are in the upper limit, but that's easy to fix. What is the question? Isn't this just a rewriting of "$x^n/n!$"?

Comment: @Macavity Could you please list a reference? I'm also interested in OP's question.

Comment: It seems like it clearly _works_, the question is how many assumptions need to be justified in explaining why.  This is not my area, but it seems like you need more than just an algebra of operators—you need a norm, so that you can say what it means for a geometric series of operators to "converge".

Comment: As you can verify after the fact,

$$\left(1-\int\right)\left(1+\int+\iint+\iiint+...\right)=1-\iiiint...$$
with total rigor, provided the integrals exist.

Comment: Try getting to Theorem 2.3.1 in http://www.springer.com/cda/content/document/cda_downloaddocument/9781441904577-c1.pdf

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(Write $(T f)(x)=\int_0^x f(t) \, dt$, so that we don't get conflict with what $\int^k$ means)

I shall work on the space of continuous functions on $[0,R]$ completed using the supremum norm $\| f \| = \| f \|_{\infty} := \sup_{x \in [0,R]} |f(x)|$; call this $X$. It should be clear that $T$ maps $X \to X$.

Let $x>0$ be sufficiently small ($<1$ will do). Then $ \| T f \| \leqslant x \| f \| $, using the trivial bound $ \left| \int_a^b f \right| \leq (b-a) \sup_{a<x<b} |f(x)| $, and so $\| T^k f \| \leq x^k\| f \|$. (In fact, using the [Cauchy formula for repeated integration](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_formula_for_repeated_integration), we can do better: $\| T^k f \| \leq (x^k/k!)\| f \|$, and then $x$ can be any real value. It should be easy for you to improve my calculation to work on the whole line with this.)

Now consider the operator sum
$$ S_n = I + \sum_{k=1}^n T^k, $$
where $I$ is the identity operator (your $1$); this is called the [Neumann Series](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Neumann_series) of $T$. We can prove this converges to the inverse of $(I-T)$: we have
$$ S_n (I-T)f = (I-T)S_n f = f - T^{n+1} f, $$
so
$$ \| S_n (I-T)f-f \| = \| T^{n+1} f \| < x^{n+1} f \to 0 $$
as $n \to \infty$. (Similarly for $(I-T)S_n f$.) Since $X$ is complete, we therefore conclude that $ S_{n} f \to (I-T)^{-1}f $.

The above shows that your calculation with the geometric series works, since $(T^k 1)(x) = x^k/k!$, and an argument with the [contraction mapping theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Banach_fixed-point_theorem) will show that $e^x$ is the unique such function.